# Обновление страницы из java бина

Tags: jsf, java

Здравствуйте! Можно ли при использовании jsf обновить текущую страницу(или ее часть) из кода java бина?

Answer (score 2):

Чистый JSF

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("clientId");
```

Если используете PrimeFaces

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("clientId");
```

Если используете OmniFaces

```
Ajax.update("clientId");
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно обновить текущую страницу полностью можно использовать:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
```

Comment: это не обновление а повторная загрузка текущей страницы

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Ищите тут: [ICEfaces Component Suite](http://component-showcase.icesoft.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface).